# Zend Framework 1.11 + Doctrine 2 Integration: Autoloading Models models/user.php -> Model\User

Tags: zend-framework, autoload, doctrine-orm

How can I setup autoloading such that I can have my directory structure like

```
/application
    /models  <<--- plural
    ...
```

And have Zend/Doctrine Autoloader load `Application\Model\User`. Notice Model is singular.

Currently I have autoloader setup as follows (in `Bootstrap.php _initDoctrine()`)

```
$zendAutoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// Symfony
$autoloader = array(new ClassLoader('Symfony'), 'loadClass');
$zendAutoloader->pushAutoloader($autoloader, 'Symfony\\');

// Doctrine 
$autoloader = array(new ClassLoader('Doctrine'), 'loadClass');
$zendAutoloader->pushAutoloader($autoloader, 'Doctrine\\');

// Models
$autoloader = array(new ClassLoader('Application\\Model', realpath(__DIR__ . '/models')), 'loadClass');
$zendAutoloader->pushAutoloader($autoloader, 'Application\\Model');

// Proxies
$autoloader = array(new ClassLoader('Application\\Model\\Proxy', realpath(__DIR__ . '/models/proxies')), 'loadClass');
$zendAutoloader->pushAutoloader($autoloader, 'Application\\Model\\Proxy');
```

Currently, when I try using `Application\Model\User`, I get

> `require(D:\Projects\Tickle\application\models\Application\Model\User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Its trying to include `application\models\Application\Model\User.php`. hmm its wierder than I expected. How can I fix it anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$modelsClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Application\Model', __DIR__ . '/models');
$modelsClassLoader->register();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this was to use Doctrine's autoloader/`ClassLoader` instead of Zend's

```
// disable Zend Autoloader
spl_autoload_unregister(array('Zend_Loader_Autoloader','autoload'));

// use Doctrine2's Class Loader
$autoloader = new ClassLoader('Zend');
$autoloader->setNamespaceSeparator('_');
$autoloader->register();

// Symfony
$autoloader = new ClassLoader('Symfony');
$autoloader->register();

// Doctrine 
$autoloader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine');
$autoloader->register();

// Application
$autoloader = new ClassLoader('Application', realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'));
$autoloader->register();
```

1 of my mistakes was that I should be using `realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')` which with my directory structure, ...

```
/Tickle (Project name)
    /application
        /models
            /proxies
...
```

Points to "Tickle", so that when doctrine appends the path "Application/Models/User.php" it will look like "/Tickle/Application/Models/Users.php" which exists